# java.lang.NullPointerException thrown when launching Selenium project

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm a newbie in Selenium.  I created a simple testcase with Selenium IDE recorder, saved it, and exported it as a Java file.
I created a new Java project on Eclipse, imported external jars and the Java code according to http://university.utest.com/selenium-basics-part-1-how-to-set-up-selenium/ tutorial.
When trying to run this it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` without pointing to any specific problem. Nothing appears on Console. The error appears as pop-up notification.
I have no idea what's wrong.
I guess the problem is with some Eclipse Run settings or something like this.
The java code is:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;  
import org.junit.After;  
import org.junit.Before;  
import org.junit.Test;  
import static org.junit.Assert.*;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  

public class wrongLogin {  
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://am2-qa.einsteinworld.info/en/activities/view");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrongLogin() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/en/login/view/");
        selenium.type("id=txtUserName", "forg");
        selenium.type("id=txtPassword", "sdsdsd");
        selenium.click("id=loginSubmit");
        assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("id=userDetailsError"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

The screenshot can be seen here 'http://www.filedropper.com/npepop-up'

**UPD** After totally erasing Eclipse with all it's settings and re-installing it from scratch now it works OK

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: It even doesn't start running. It appears as pop-up notification: 'Launching wrongLogin' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during 'Launching wrongLogin'. wrongLogin is my Java file name. Nothing appears on the Console.

Comment: Are you getting an NPE in a popup message? Add the screenshot please. Clean and build your project. If the error continues then try using a new workspace.

Comment: Screenshot link added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and build your project and try again

OR

1. Exit Eclipse
2. Go to your workspace
3. Delete .metadata file
4. Start Eclipse
5. Import all your projects in Eclipse

OR

Just create a new Workspace and all your java files in the new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it seems like you may have forgotten to start the selenium server before running the tests.

Please try running the selenium server for running Selenium Server
Go to the directory where Selenium RC’s server is located and run the following from a command-line console.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version-number>.jar
```

Comment: Starting Selenium Server or not doesn't make any change. I'm sorry.

Comment: What's the line number at which you get the NPE?

Comment: As I wrote above there is no line number, the error occur on launching the project. Nothing appears in Console. The error appears as pop-up.

Comment: Which browser's popup is that? I tried the same code in IntellijIdea it works perfectly fine. Can you paste the selenium server logs?

Comment: I run it in Eclipse, this is Eclipse error pop-up. It doesn't even try to start a browser. I'm almost sure it's some kind of environment settings problem but I have no idea which.

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if you have any errors in the eclipse log?
You can activate it by going to Window -> Show view -> Error Log
and see if there's any error there?
(I know this isn't an answer, just dont have enough rep to post as comment)

Comment: thank you for this comment. After 2-3 days of attempts to fix the problem I finally removed the eclipse and currently installing it again from the scratch....